# Date strings in the form "2011-01-27T04:59:00Z" — some browsers accept them, some don't. Why?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm getting a date string in the form `"2011-01-27T04:59:00Z"` from a web service call. Firefox and Chrome have no problem parsing the string with `var d = new Date("2011-01-27T04:59:00Z")`, but Safari and IE won't stand for it.

I can parse the string myself and feed it to `Date.parse()` or `Date.UTC()`, but I'm wondering why (1) such a disparity exists among browsers in something so basic as a Date object, and (2) why a public API would return a date string in a format that is rejected by Safari and (especially) IE.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your last point: I can write a public API myself that outputs a date string in Dutch, like "den zevenentwintigsten januari tweeduizendelf"; I fear no browser understands that...

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: I'm talking about a public API for a commercial service that makes money off of people using its API. My question is not whether someone *can* write an API that's indifferent to cross-browser quirks; I already know it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you two questions, I would say

1. <strike>It's a relic from pre-Browser War I. ECMAScript spec was poorly written, and browser supports whatever they (don't) want to.</strike>
2. <strike>It's ISO 8601 format, invented years after Javascript Date object. Even in php it was added after php 5.0. Date object was original design to take RFC 2822 format.</strike>

**Corrections per comments:**

1. `Date.prototype.parse` was introduced without a specification that state the date format it should support. Even when it was standardized in [ECMAScript 3](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-15.html#a-15.9.4.2), the spec didn't define what date format it should support. In Dec. 2009, [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.9.1.15) defined that `Date` should support ISO 8601 format as specified in the question, yet for released versions, at time of writing, only Gecko/Firefox implemented the feature. (Webkit had implemented in the nightly version from my test)
2. For unknown reason, even though ISO 8601 was written in 1988, it was not until recently the web protocols/programming languages had begun support the format. PHP supported the format in `date()` function only after version 5. At the beginning of the Internet, protocols are used to take time in RFC 822/2822 format, which is human-readable for English users.
3. In my opinion, an API should use Unix time to describe time if it's only intend for machines.

Comment: Last but not least, API designers are not necessarily geniuses ;)

Comment: Agreed. However ISO 8601 is far more convenient for computers to parse. I would use it if it was me who designed the API - oh way, I will use Unix Epoch and represent time in a integral - in this way computers don't have to parse it at all.

Comment: Indeed: for `Date.prototype.parse`, [ECMAScript 3](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-15.html#a-15.9.4.2) doesn't mention a specific string format, whereas [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.9.1.15) does.

Comment: +1 to Marcel for reference link. So Gecko/Firefox is supporting the future spec on this.

Comment: Future spec? ECMAScript 5 was [officially published](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) in December 2009.

Comment: Excuse me?  ISO 8601 was written in 1988, years _before_ the WWW was even invented, let alone Mocha, er, LiveScript, er, Javascript...

It's more that RFC 822 was written by Americans, to simplify writing mails for Americans, since the internet only existed in the USA at that time. (And yes, RFC 822 was written before ISO-8601 existed. And RFC 2822 copied 822's date format for compatibility purposes).

Comment: +1 for prove me wrong and the history lesson. Do you have any explanation for that fact ISO 8601 is adopted far later than the time of it's invention? Happy to know.

Comment: As for that, I’d have to go out on a limb and say "for the same reason the US still use miles, feet, hands, inches etc."... :-)
Srsly, it was adopted gradually (and in many cases partially) by countries and organisations the world over whenever they felt it addressed a need.  South Africa and Canada were using it by 1989.  XML (and its use in Web services) helped its spread in the IT world. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601_usage

Comment: And the problem in this case is that the ECMAScript specification was written after Netscape's JavaScript 1.3. At that time, Microsoft already used it's own browser scripting language(s), JScript.

Comment: Made correction in the answer; thanks guys, really learned a lot.